# gcc segfault with no optimization

Tags: c, gcc

The following code compiles but gives segmentation fault when no GCC optimizations are used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define n 10000000

int main()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Array with size %ld\n", n * sizeof(double));
    double a[n];
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -O0 a.c && ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ gcc -O1 a.c && ./a.out 
Array with size 80000000
```

I tested with -O1, -O2, -O3 and even with -Og it works. But with -O0 it segfaults. I am using GCC 5.3.0.

If I remove the fprintf, or if I change the array to static double[N], there is no segmentation fault.

Why? What is happening?

Comment: Unrelated, but the common naming convention for constants is all uppercase, and something more descriptive than a single letter, so for example: `ARRAY_SIZE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've just run out of stack space.

`double a[n];` gets allocated on the stack, and it's around 40 (80?) megabytes in size.

Making it `static` means it's no longer on the stack - and turning on optimizations will mean that the compiler never actually allocates it.

Comment: What do you mean by "turning on optimizations will mean that the compiler never actually allocates it." ?

Comment: @Heitor - The compiler can tell that `a` is unused, It's a simple optimization.

Answer (score 7):

The default *stack* size is usually small (such as 8MB). Your array size is probably too big and overflows the stack. 
You can try to change the default stack size on *nix systems with:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

In the general case, there's no portable solution to identify whether a given array allocation with automatic storage duration (aka "stack") is going to be successful. So it's better to use `malloc()` when you are allocating a reasonably large object(s).